# Binding ListView not Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I have a problem trying to bind my list to list view and I get an empty list view. I have tried changining my list to a property as I have seen this solve other peoples problem with no luck, any help appreciated.

Here is the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="key_stage_level_2_app.Window7"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
 Title="Window7" Height="600" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

<Grid>
    <TabControl Height="536" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tabControl1"      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="778">
        <TabItem Header="Results2" Name="tabItem2">
            <Grid>
                <ListView Height="323" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="107,96,0,0" Name="listView2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=someList}" >
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="80"  Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="80 " Header="Result" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Result}"/>    
                        </GridView>   
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Here is the code behind

```
namespace key_stage_level_2_app
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window7.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Window7 : Window
{

    App app = (App)App.Current;
    private List<Pupil> someList { get; set; }


    public Window7()
    {
        someList = new List<Pupil>();

        foreach (Pupil pupil in app.PupilList)
        {
            someList.Add(pupil);

        }
        someList.Add(new Pupil
        {
            Name = "Simon",
            Result = 100,
            Grade = 100.00,
            ExtensionWork = true,
            TakenTest = true

        });
        Console.WriteLine("someList size = " + someList.Count);

        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

And the Class

```
class Pupil
{

    public String name;
    int result;
    double grade;
    bool extensionWork;
    bool takenTest;

    public Pupil(String Pname, int Presult, double Pgrade, bool PextensionWork, bool PtakenTest)
    {
        Name = Pname;
        Result = Presult;
        Grade = Pgrade;
        ExtensionWork = PextensionWork;
        TakenTest = PtakenTest;

    }
    public Pupil()
    {

    }

    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }


    public int Result
    {
        get { return result; }
        set { result = value; }
    }


    public double Grade
    {
        get { return grade; }
        set { grade = value; }
    }


    public bool ExtensionWork
    {
        get { return extensionWork; }
        set { extensionWork = value; }
    }


    public bool TakenTest
    {
        get { return takenTest; }
        set { takenTest = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your class access modifier to:

```
public class Pupil
```

and make the someList property public:

```
public List<Pupil> SomeList { get; set; }
```

So the view can actually see it.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting nothing because you are creating new list but your list is empty, do this:

```
someList = new List<Pupil>();

someList.Add(new Pupil
        {
            Name = "Simon",
            Result = 100,
            Grade = 100.00,
            ExtensionWork = true,
            TakenTest = true

        });

        foreach (Pupil pupil in app.PupilList)
        {
            someList.Add(pupil);

        }
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine("someList size = " + someList.Count); is == 2 the list is not empty thanks anyway

Comment: the list contains a pupil added from another window plus i added a new pupil on this window to ensure the list was not empty.

Comment: the foreach loop is iterating a different list which is adding the pupil to this list which contains one pupil, then i create a new pupil and add that to the list. and the ouput to console is 2.

Answer (score 1):

After InitializeComponent(); add the following line:

```
DataContext = this;
```

so that the View knows where to get the someList from.

In addition, both Window7 and Pupil should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to allow updating and avoid memory leaks.

Comment: I have tried this previous with no luck.. and I have this in XAML DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" so should not need that. thanks anyway